# Custom rails validator that allows one of two items to be null but not both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm working on an assignment that has, among many other, the following requirement:

```
Define custom validator that permits first_name or last_name to be null but not both
```

I have something that works but I'm quite certain it is not correct:

```
def at_least_one_name
  if first_name.nil? && last_name.nil?
    errors.add(:first_name, "Must contain at least a first or last name")
  end
end
```

I don't know how I should be testing this completely. What I have above is only testing if both are nil. The fact that I'm only adding `:first_name` to the errors array tells me already that something is amiss.

Would this be an `if/else`? Do those work in validations?

**EDIT:** The tests that I'm trying to make pass:

```
it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name" do
  expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")).to_not be_valid
end
it "allows a Profile with a null first name when last name present" do
  expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>"Smith", :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
end
it "allows a Profile with a null last name when first name present" do
  expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"Joe", :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
end
```

Comment: You should mark answer right if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are using `&&` operator. Which check for both. try `||` instead that will check for either. Change like below.

```
def at_least_one_name
  if first_name.present? || last_name.present?
    errors.add(:first_name, "Must contain at least a first or last name")
  end
end
```

There are other ways also like this :

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, unless: ->(user){user.last_name.present?}
validates :last_name, presence: true, unless: ->(user){user.first_name.present?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the information provided by `Dipak G.` I was able to come to a solution:

```
def at_least_one_name
  unless first_name.present? || last_name.present?
    errors.add(:user, "Must contain at least a first or last name"
  end
end
```

This works and doesn't break any other tests.